# When does didUpdateLocation get called?

Tags: swift, location, mapkit, theory, cllocation

Let's say you want to focus your MapView on the current location, then you write some code in `didUpdateLocation` which processes the current location coordinates.

But if you don't call  `requestLocation` or `startUpdatingLocaion` on your `CLLocationManager` object, the method never gets called. Is that correct?

But wether you call `requestLocation` or `startUpdatingLocation` if you look on your `MapView` the blue dot which shows your location moves (e.g. you simulate movement) but didUpdateLocation won't get called automatically.

I am trying to understand why they made a delegate method when you kind of have to call it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the startUpdatingLocation ONCE and the didUpdateLocation delegate method will be called every time when the location changes. This is very different compared to what you say.

Comment: Yes maybe I wasn't clear enough. But what I wanted to say is that didUpdateLocations always needs a start off to her called. But nevertheless in your mapview you can See the Blue dot is moving (e.g. if you simulate movement) but didUpdateLocations doesn't get called. I will update my question.

Comment: Well, it's kind of weird anyways that the blue dot is moving, but it can be expected behaviour that the dot is updated, but the delegate is not called, as you did not subscribe for it But the delegate implementation behaviour is as expected in my opinion. You have to call the start to receive updates.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. I just wanted to know if I am thinking in the complete wrong direction but it seems that it is just kind of unexpected.